# Why does the batch file sometimes hangs when executing an application?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I am busy currently trying to automate some manual startup tasks on Windows 10 using a batch file. But I am facing a weird issue.

I want to make a batch script that will start **Xming** using some parameters. So I thought I can just put this in the batch file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow
```

If I execute this in an open command window it will work fine even multiple times in sequence without starting more than 1 instance of **Xming**. But once I put only this line into a bat file and execute that script it sometimes works and sometimes hangs forever.

I have been searching with Google for a while now and I can't find anything describing the issue I am having. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the output of a command prompt illustrating my problem:

```
C:\Users\JS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

C:\Users\JS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

C:\Users\JS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

...

C:\Users\JS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

C:\Users\JS>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

C:\Users\JS>
C:\Users\JS>cd desktop

C:\Users\JS\Desktop>startup.bat

C:\Users\JS\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow

... Hangs forever here
```

Where startup.bat only contains 1 line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow
```

Comment: Does the `Start` command help you? `@Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow`, if not then you may need to run `Cmd.exe` with your command bolted onto the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also to use command **START** like [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) to start this application explicitly in a separate process.

```
start "Xming" /D"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Xming" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow
```

After Windows command interpreter has executed the command **START** it immediately continues executing the next line in batch file while **Xming** is executed in a separate process running parallel to command process executing the batch file.

The first parameter of **START** is the optional title which needs to be specified if any other argument must be enclosed in double quotes as otherwise this double quoted argument would be interpreted as window title.

The second argument starting with `/D` defines the start in directory (current directory) for the application to run. Here is specified that the current directory for **Xming** is its program files directory. This could be important as some applications are not good coded and do not work correct if the current directory of the process on starting it is not the program files directory of the application.

All other arguments are the application to run with its arguments.

Run in a command prompt window `start /?` to get output the help for this command explaining it and its options.